# How to create cubic box menu

Tags: html, css

How can I create cubic menu like this image: (When I hover on menu item)
[image]

```css
ul li {
        border-left: 1px solid #515151;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px 1rem;
        font-size: 0.625rem;
      }

      ul {
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        border: 0 solid #515151;
        border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
        width: 275px;
      }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was my prototype for the 3d box](https://jsfiddle.net/3849camk/)

I then applied the prototype to your menu. What I like least is the need to set a default size. You can find in the comments where to set the height (the variabler `--height`) and width (`--width`) of the individual menu items or the height of the extrusion (`--extrude`).

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform-style: flat;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 275px;
  --extrude: 0px; 
  --height: 35px; /* Your menu height */
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.home {
  --width: 75px; /* Your static width */
  z-index: 1000;
}
.aboutus {
  --width: 85px; /* Your static width */
  z-index: 999;
}

.products {
  --width: 85px; /* Your static width */
  z-index: 998;
}
.contactus {
  --width: 100px; /* Your static width */
  z-index: 997;
}



.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: -200px 300px;
}

.wrap * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--height);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color:#000000;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translateZ(var(--extrude));
}

ul li:hover {
  --extrude: 30px; /* Your extrude height */
}

ul li:hover .front {
  background-color: #f7a62f;
  color:#ffffff;
}

ul li:hover .front,
ul li:hover .bottom,
ul li:hover .left {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}



.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--extrude);
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--height) - var(--extrude))) rotateX(270deg);
}

.left {
  width: var(--extrude);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: translateZ(var(--extrude)) rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap home">
      <div class="front">
        home
      </div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap aboutus">
      <div class="front">
        About Us
      </div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap products">
      <div class="front">
        Products
      </div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap contactus">
      <div class="front">
        Contact Us
      </div>
      <div class="bottom"></div>
      <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example,it uses combination of `:before`&`:after`,(I know there is some lag)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

ul {
  display:inline-flex;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg);
  width:100%;
}
.list-item {
  background: #000;
  color: #575757;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #060606;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.list-item:hover {
  background: #ff6e42;
  color: #fffcfb;
  transform: translate(0.9em, -0.9em);
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.list-item:hover{
  z-index:100;
}
.list-item:hover:before, .list-item:hover:after {
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
}
.list-item:hover:before {
  background: #b65234;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: -1em;
}
.list-item:hover:after {
  background: #b65234;
  width: 1em;
  bottom: -2.5em;
  left: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}
.list-item:before, .list-item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  width: 0.5em;
}
.list-item:after {
  height: 4em;
  background: #000;
  bottom: -2.25em;
  left: 1.5em;
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(0, 45deg);
}
.list-item:before {
  height: 2.5em;
  background: #000;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: -0.5em;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class='list-item' href=''>
      hi
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='list-item' href=''>
      hello
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='list-item' href=''>
      i am a
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='list-item' href=''>
      menu
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='list-item' href=''>
      item
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is good. But there is a big diffrence between my image and your answer.
Default state must be flat. And when menu is hovered, I need to show all borders (vertical, horizontal and oblique)